# How to number an indented list

Tags: vb.net

I would like to know a good way to number an indented list.
See image for an impression.
In short, the list is a Structured BoM(Bill of Material) from the cad program Inventor that I use.
The list is made up of parts(.ipt) and sub-assemblies(.iam).
The rules are now made up of 3 parts separated by a '|'.
Part 1 the level of indent, part 2 the path of the component itself, part 3 the component if there is a parent relationship.
The order of the lines is as it should be, it's just a matter of numbering them.
I hope this is a typical case for which the wheel was already invented.
Goal/idea is to convert the list into another list.
I'm not new to programming, for next, split, do while loop, list, dictionaries etc. I've seen them all pass by and used them here and there, I just don't have any experience how to do this efficiently.
In short, any help is more than welcome, thanks in advance.

[Example with a few numbers filled in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XEqA.png)

Comment: It's a little unclear exactly what you're asking (to me at least)  Are you asking how to concatenate a number, to a string to create a new string or maintain the numbering pattern or maybe, how to present this numbered list?  Either way, you need to update you question with what you've attempted so far.

Comment: Agree with @Hursey - the question needs more details for answers to be useful.  StackOverflow works best (IMO) when there is actual code to review.  But if you are looking to brainstorm an algorithm to solve your problem, and don't have code yet, say so!  But just like having code to review, it helps to have some initial idea of your attempts to solve the problem.  If you are indeed at the brainstorm stage, do you have an initial algorithm in mind?